# While running pdflatex withing TexStudio92,12,22 under MikTex), I get "pdflatex: security risk: running with elevated privileges" error

Tags: pdftex, pdf

While running pdflatex within TexStudio (2,12,22 under MikTex), I get "pdflatex: security risk: running with elevated privileges" error.  My OS is win7.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? 
I am facing the same error.